# remove points located within a specific area - python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to remove points that are located within a specific area. Using below, I'm hoping to remove points that are located within the blue box. Ideally, I'd map out a polygon that followed the contour of the circle more closely. This is just a rough description.

I'm currently applying a crude subset to the y-coordinates:

```
df = df[df['A'] > 0]
df = df[df['C'] > 0]
```

While this gets the majority of points, I'm hoping to improve the method.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(-25,125,size=(500, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.set_xlim(-50, 150)
ax.set_ylim(-50, 150)

x = ([1.25,0.5,-0.25,0.5,1.25,-10,-10,1.25]) 
y = ([75,62.5,50,37.5,25,25,75,75])
plt.plot(x,y)

A = df['A']
B = df['B']

C = df['C']
D = df['D']

plt.scatter(df['A'], df['B'], color = 'purple', alpha = 0.2); 
plt.scatter(df['C'], df['D'], color = 'orange', alpha = 0.2); 

Oval_patch = mpl.patches.Ellipse((50,50), 100, 150, color = 'k', fill = False)

ax.add_patch(Oval_patch)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to store your polygon (the `<Line2D object>`) in a variable like this:

```
line = plt.plot(x,y)
```

Which enables you to utilise the [get_path() method](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.get_path) to get the underlying path object, which has a builtin [contains_points() method](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/api/path_api.html#matplotlib.path.Path.contains_points).

Next, include the following lines:

```
pts = df[['C','D']]
mask = line[0].get_path().contains_points(pts)
plt.scatter(df['C'][mask],df['D'][mask],color="red",zorder=10)
```

and you should be able to verify that the correct points are selected by the mask:

[image: masked points highlighted in red]

Now, to remove the points within your selected region, you can use `~mask` to negate the boolean mask, i.e. use:

```
pts = df[['A','B']]
mask_ab = line[0].get_path().contains_points(pts)
pts = df[['C','D']]
mask_cd = line[0].get_path().contains_points(pts)

plt.scatter(df['A'][~mask_ab], df['B'][~mask_ab], color = 'purple', alpha = 0.2) 
plt.scatter(df['C'][~mask_cd], df['D'][~mask_cd], color = 'orange', alpha = 0.2)
```

to get this result:

[image: masked points removed]

Comment: Cheers. Thanks @Asmus